# Pseudo elements is to far from my DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'm doing cookie bar for website

```
<div id="cookie" class="md_blkn">
    <div id="cookie-content">
         <h3 class="pts">WE USE COOKIES</h3>
        <p>We use cookies to ensure that we give you the best experience on our website. If you continue without changing your settings, we will assume that you are happy to receive all cookies from this website. We use cookies to ensure that we give you the best experience on our website.</p> <a class="btn-gray-light-solid-s mbs" href="#">OKAY GOT IT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've managed how to add icon via CSS lef to the paragraph, however I can't keep it left to cookie-content element. Could someone give me hint what I'm doing wrong? I believe it's easy for skilled CSS guy :)

Here is a live example (the (I) circle must be located near to content):
http://jsfiddle.net/dpastov/kU9F6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a percentage when setting the top position so it can scale to the content height.

```
#cookie-content
{
    position: relative;
}

#cookie-content:before
{
    top: 40%;
    left: -75px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kU9F6/3/)

Comment: I need to keep it near to paragraph, if you make panel bigger (I) will go to far from paragraph. So I wish to know how can I keep it always near the P

Comment: basically I think I must do something with #cookie-content:before but I do not know what

Comment: @Dmytro I just updated my answer to work how you would like it.

Comment: great, my mistake was I did not use position: relative for my cookie-content block.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `margin-top:some value` to your css selector `#cookie-content:before`
here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kU9F6/1/)